# How to display set of buttons in bottom of each activity in android app

Tags: android, button

I want display some set of buttons (Settings, Shopping Cart, Offers) in all the activity except one in my android app.

Currently i can think of adding this layout in each of my activity.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#FFFF00" >


    <Button android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        />

    <Button android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Having this kind of structure have lot of issues.
1. When create new activity, add this code.
2. Code duplicate.
3. Code maintenance.
4. Handling these button click in all activities.

I can not use action bar as i know they shown on top of screen

I am sure there should be some better way in android to achieve this, but can not figure out yet.

Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use include tag like this:

```
<include
android:id="@+id/inc"
layout="@layout/tablayout"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
/>
```

and make another xml file:- `tablayout.xml` // inside layout

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:background="#FFFF00" >
<Button android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    />
<Button android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

you can use buttons click like this code in Global class

```
 //Globalclass extends Activity

 protected void onbutton1() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Profile.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
   }
```

Comment: @Devesh Agrawal may be it will help you

Comment: if this answer is correct please check this correct

Comment: Thanks for response. This solves my problem 50%. Can u help us how to handle the event on buttons? Do i need to handle it independently on each activity where i am including this?

Comment: just you can use every button on click listener or id in every class where you want or you can use this to make a global class and declare these buttons in that class and click listeners also in to global class .

Answer (score 0):

Create only on Activity and add Fragments in that activity instead on creating new Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Set 3 buttons in fragment and use the fragment by tag in other activity's layout.